# Sort Column and Hide Rows without specified text in column using VBA Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, hide

I'm looking to use a VBA Macro which will 'sort' a column but 'hide' all the other text.

The column is populated with three letter text, i.e. MFA, KDB, OPA etc...

This is the code I currently have found:

```
Sub SortByName()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("V:V"), _
                             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                             Order:=xlAscending, _
                             CustomOrder:="MFA", _
                             DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SetRange .Range("A:AA")
        .Sort.Header = xlYes
        .Sort.MatchCase = False
        .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Sort.Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

This code works well, but it does not hide the undesired rows with text that is not 'MFA'

Many thanks :)

Comment: I think you need `Autofilter`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, use `AutoFilter` to hide rows not containing `'MFA'`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortByName()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("V:V"), _
                             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                             Order:=xlAscending, _
                             CustomOrder:="MFA", _
                             DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SetRange .Range("A:AA")
        .Sort.Header = xlYes
        .Sort.MatchCase = False
        .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Sort.Apply

        .UsedRange.Columns("V").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="MFA"
        'Or: .Range("A:AA").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="MFA"

    End With

End Sub
```